# Run rails sidekiq as a system service on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu-16.04, bundler, sidekiq

I have system requirement below:

1. `Ubuntu 16.04`
2. `ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]`
3. `Rails 4.2.5`

i can run command `bundle exec sidekiq -q queue` inside my project without error. Unfortunately when i try to create system service with following filename single_profile_crawl_worker.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=sidekiq

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/jaisanas/Documents/work/myproject
ExecStart=/home/jaisanas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@scraper/bin/bundle exec sidekiq -q tahilalat

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

then i run command:

> sudo systemctl start single_profile_crawl_worker.service

then when i check the service status, by following command:

> sudo systemctl status single_profile_crawl_worker.service

it returns error like below:

```
single_profile_crawl_worker.service - sidekiq
 Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/single_profile_crawl_worker.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Kam 2018-08-09 14:13:43 WIB; 5s ago
      Process: 9822 ExecStart=/home/jaisanas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@scraper/bin/bundle exec sidekiq -q tahilalat (code=exited, status=127)
     Main PID: 9822 (code=exited, status=127)

    Agu 09 14:13:43 jaisanas-X456URK systemd[1]: Started sidekiq.
    Agu 09 14:13:43 jaisanas-X456URK bundle[9822]: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby_executable_hooks’: No such file or directory
    Agu 09 14:13:43 jaisanas-X456URK systemd[1]: single_profile_crawl_worker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
    Agu 09 14:13:43 jaisanas-X456URK systemd[1]: single_profile_crawl_worker.service: Unit entered failed state.
    Agu 09 14:13:43 jaisanas-X456URK systemd[1]: single_profile_crawl_worker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

it said `/usr/bin/env: ‘ruby_executable_hooks’: No such file or directory`. Then i've tried several solution like installing ruby_executable_hooks by running `sudo gem install --user-install executable-hooks` it doesn't work, anyone know what's wrong with my steps create this sidekiq system service ?

Comment: You're doing it wrong, first you need to run systemd as user not as root then you need to load rvm before run sidekiq.

Comment: I believe you can configure systemd to run your service as your user so permissions are set correctly for accessing all your files within `/home/jaisanas`. Try `User=jaisanas` in your .service file.

Comment: hi @MikePerham , i have add `User=jaisanas` to my .service file, although i'm not getting error but my `service` failed with exit code status = 127, i'm sure that i place correct bundle path.

Comment: nvm i change `/bin` to `/wrappers` then it works

Comment: hi @MikePerham, would you like to tell me how to create ubuntu service to run `daemonize sidekiq` ?

Comment: nope!  I don't recommend daemonization and won't help people use it.